# How to add a column from a text file in the end of another one using Bash?

Tags: bash, text, awk

So, if I have a text file with one column and want to print it in the end or beginning of another text file, is it possible just with Bash or AWK through the console (Ubuntu)?

File 1 example:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

File 2 example:

```
1 .  
2 ,` 
3 > 
4 <
5 [
```

What I want:

`1` `.` `a`
`2` `,` `b`
`3` `>` `c`
`4` `<` `d`
`5` `[` `e`

The columns are separated by "\t".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste`:

```
$ paste 2.txt 1.txt 
1       .       a
2       ,       b
3       >       c
4       <       d
5       [       e
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah. The OP is using tabs as delimiters though, so your answer is slightly less correct :)